# Creating more complex EPNs in Esper CEP

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I have just implemented a simple example of Esper CEP in java. Similar to [example](https://github.com/adrianmilne/esper-demo-nuclear/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cor/cep/subscriber/MonitorEventSubscriber.java).

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.addEventType("SensorEvent",
                    test.SensorEvent.class.getName());
            EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager
                    .getDefaultProvider(config);

            String expression = "select * from SensorEvent where sensor11 >= 1.00";

            EPStatement statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression);

            MyListener listener = new MyListener();

            statement.addListener(listener);
```

However, in this example only a simple filter EPA is assumed. Now I would like to combine several EPAs within the runtime, similar to the following example. Unfortunately I can't find any examples for such an implementation:
[image]
Does anyone have an example?.

Thank you in advance

Edit: So far i did it like user650839 said:

```
String expression = "@name('EPA1') insert into EPA1 select * from SensorEvent where sensor11 >= 1";
        String expression2 = "@name('EPA2') insert into EPA2 select * from SensorEvent where sensor12 >= 1";
        String expression3 ="@name('EPA3') select * from EPA1#time(100) as epa1, EPA2#time(200) as epa2 where epa1.id = epa2.id";
EPStatement statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression);
            EPStatement statement2 = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression2);
            EPStatement statement3 = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression3);
 MyListener listener = new MyListener();

            statement.addListener(listener);
            statement2.addListener(listener);
            statement3.addListener(listener);
```

The code is perfectly compiled, but my event handler also responds when sensor 12 is less than 1. So I guess it's enough if one of my statements is true, but my event handler should only react if all statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

```
@name('EPA1') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11>1);
@name('EPA2') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11<1);
@name('EPA3') select count(*) from EPA3
```

or maybe, depending on what exactly the drawing means

```
@name('EPA1') insert into EPA1 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11>1);
@name('EPA2') insert into EPA2 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11<1);
@name('EPA3') select * from EPA1#time(10) as epa1, EPA2#time(20) as epa2 where epa1.sensorId = epa2.sensorId
```

Perhaps the [solution patterns](http://www.espertech.com/esper/solution-patterns/) will inspire you further.

Comment: So you mean that I can simply use your first example as an expression string?
Like this: String expression3 ="@name('EPA1') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11=1);\n" +
                                "@name('EPA2') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor12=1);\n" +
                                "@name('EPA3') select count(*) from EPA3";

            EPStatement statement3 = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression);
            
            MyListener listener = new MyListener();

            statement3.addListener(listener);

Comment: I'm asking this, because when I try to run my code I'm getting this error:
com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near ';' at line 1 column 68, please check the from clause [@name('EPA1') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor11=1);
@name('EPA2') insert into EPA3 select * from SensorEvent(sensor12=1);
@name('EPA3') select count(*) from EPA3]

Comment: Esper 8 and newer: just compile. Esper 7 and older: use modules

Comment: so I tried something and installed Esper 8. The code with my more complex statement will also be compiled error free but my CEP only recognizes the first statement. the further statements after the first EPL will be completely ignored.
This is my code:

Comment: String EPL3 ="@name('EPA1') insert into EPA1 select i,id from IEvent where i>4;\n" +
                    "@name('EPA2') insert into EPA2 select j,id from IEvent where j>6;\n" +
                    "@name('EPA4') insert into EPA4 select x,id from IEvent where x>4;\n" +
                    "@name('EPA3') insert into EPA3 select epa1.i as i,epa2.j as j,epa2.id as id from EPA1#time(100) as epa1, EPA2#time(100) as epa2 where epa1.id = epa2.id;\n" +
                    "@name('EPA5') select * from EPA4#time(100) as epa4, EPA3#time(100) as epa3 where epa3.id = epa4.id;";